# Prove that $a$ divides $b$ and $b$ divides $a$ if and only if $a = \pm b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

> Let $a$ and $b$ be nonzero integers. Prove that $a$ divides $b$ and $b$ divides $a$ if and only if $a = \pm b$.

Since this is a iff statement, I need to prove it both ways:

$\Rightarrow$ If $a=\pm b$, then  $a$ divides $b$ and $b$ divides $a$;  and

$\Leftarrow$ If $a$ divides $b$ and $b$ divides $a$, then $a=\pm b$.

I tried to prove it but I don't know how to manage the $\pm$ sign, can anyone give me a hit or suggestion to start this proof?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't the definition of $a$ dividing $b$ independent of the sign? That is, you could use the modulus-definition and do away with the sign completely, since $a$ divides $b$ if $\pm a\bmod b = 0$

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Only $\Leftarrow$ is nontrivial. But if $a$ divides $b$, then $|a|\leq|b|$. If $b$...

Answer (score 3):

If $a|b$, there is $k_1\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ak_1=b$. Moreover, $b|a$, so there is $k_2\in\mathbb{Z}$ so that $bk_2=a$. Now, substitution gives $b=ak_1=bk_1k_2$, or $1=k_1k_2$. Now you get the result, since the only invertible integers are $\pm1$

Answer (score 2):

If $a$ divides $b$, then $a = pb$ for some integer $p$ and $a \neq 0$.

If $b$ divides $a$, then $b = qa$ for some integer $q$ and $b \neq 0$.

Then $a = pqa$ and $pq = 1$. Therefore $p = q = 1$ or $p = q = -1$.

The other side is just an easy verification.

Answer (score 2):

if $a\mid b$ then $b=ka$ with $k\in \mathbb Z$. If $b\mid a$, then $a=nb$ with $n\in \mathbb Z$. Finally if $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$, $$b=knb$$
and thus $bk=1$ with $b,k\in \mathbb Z$. The only way that happen is that $b=k=\pm 1$.

Comment: Did you mean $kn = 1$?

Answer (score 0):

$|a|\overset{\large a\,\mid\: b_{\phantom{1_{1_1}}}\!\!\!\!\!\!}=\gcd(a,b)\overset{\large b\,\mid\: a_{\phantom{1_{1_1}}}\!\!\!\!\!\!}=|b|$

Comment: Added for (pedagogical) variety.